# Eigenvalues as functions of matrix's entry

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, proof-verification

Given the matrix
$$A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0& a& 0\\
a& t& a\\
0& a& 0
\end{array}\right]$$
If eigenvalues are functions of $t$, find all the values of $a$ given 
$$\frac{d\lambda}{dt} \bigg|_{t=1} = 2$$

Here is my solution, from definition, we know
$$\det(A-\lambda I) = -\lambda^3 +\lambda^2t + 2\lambda a^2 \equiv 0 \quad \forall t.$$

Now suppose $\lambda (1) \neq 0$, since it is differentiable at $t=1$, it is also continuous at $t=1$, therefore 
$$\lambda (t) \neq 0 \text{ on some } (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon) $$
thus
$$-\lambda^2 +\lambda t + 2a^2 = 0 \text{ on some } (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon) \quad\quad\quad (1) $$
take the derivative, we get
$$-2\lambda \lambda' + \lambda + t\lambda' =0 $$
with the fact that $\lambda'(1) = 2$, we see $\lambda(1) =\frac{2}{3}$. Plugging it back into $(1)$ will give two values of $a$ using quadratic formula.

Now suppose $\lambda(1) = 0$, then differentiate the characteristic polynomial, we get
$$-3\lambda^2\lambda' + 2\lambda \lambda' t + \lambda^2 + 2a^2 \lambda' \equiv 0$$
at $t=1$, $\lambda(1) = 0$ and we get 
$$2a^2 \lambda'(1) = 0$$ 
and therefore $a=0$.
However this is impossible because then we will have $\lambda_1 \equiv 0$ and $\lambda_2(t) = t$, and neither derivative is $2$ when $t=1$.

Is this correct? I normally don't see linear algebra problems like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, why don't you try the simpler method of *actually solving* the equation for $\lambda$? That would yield $$\lambda=0,\frac{t\pm \sqrt{t^2+8a^2}}{2}$$ For the nonzero $\lambda's$ thus we have $$\frac{d\lambda}{dt}=\frac{1\pm \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+8a^2}}}{2}\\\implies\frac{d\lambda}{dt}\left|_{t=1}\right.=\frac{1\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+8a^2}}}{2}=2\\\implies a=\pm\frac{i}{3}$$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: Okay, thank you. I do get the same solutions. I just thought the derivative will be messy to compute directly, I guess it isn't too bad.

Comment: Yeah, as it turns out, in this case it is not too bad, but if the polynomial itself is hard to solve we require some different route.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues that you did not address. First of all the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is defined implicitly by $-\lambda^3 +\lambda^2t + 2\lambda a^2=0$. Now it is worth noting that for a fixed $t$ the function may admit more than one real root. Obviously 0 is a root for all $t$. And you have assumed that $\lambda(1) \neq 0$ so you are "choosing" the roots. There should be some rule to govern this otherwise it does not make much sense.